# Directional light in worldSpace is dependent on viewMatrix

Tags: opengl, glsl

I try to get my glsl shader to calculate a directional light for me but I run into the problem that the direction seems to be dependend on the viewMatrix while I want to specify it in worldSpace.
My initial idea was to just multipy the worldSpace Vector with the viewMatrix(

```
Vector4f dir = new Vector4f(dirLight.direction, 1);
dir.mul(window.getCamera().viewMatrix);
```

) in the code before setting the direction uniform but it seems that the light still changes depended on my viewMatrix, so I obviously do something wrong.
the relevant code of my shader:

```
//vertex shader

layout (location =0) in vec3 position;
layout (location =1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location =2) in vec3 vertexNormal;
layout (location=3) in vec4 jointWeights;
layout (location=4) in ivec4 jointIndices;

out vec3 gmvVertexNormal;
out vec3 gmvVertexPos;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;


struct Material 
{
    vec3 color;
    int hasTexture;
    float reflectance;
};

uniform Material material;



void main()
{
    vec4 mvPos = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0);
    gmvVertexNormal = normalize(modelViewMatrix * vec4(vertexNormal, 0.0)).xyz;
    gmvVertexPos = position;
}

//geometry shader
layout ( triangles ) in;
layout ( triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

out vec3 mvVertexNormal;
out vec3 mvVertexPos;

in vec3 gmvVertexNormal[3];
in vec3 gmvVertexPos[3];

vec3 calculateTriangleNormal(){
    vec3 tangent = gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz - gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz;
    vec3 bitangent = gl_in[2].gl_Position.xyz - gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz;
    vec3 normal = cross(tangent, bitangent);    
    return normalize(normal);
}

void main()
{
    vec4 mvPos = modelViewMatrix * vec4(gmvVertexPos[0], 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPos;
    mvVertexNormal=calculateTriangleNormal();
    mvVertexPos=mvPos.xyz;
    EmitVertex();
    mvPos = modelViewMatrix * vec4(gmvVertexPos[1], 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPos;
    mvVertexNormal=calculateTriangleNormal();
    mvVertexPos=mvPos.xyz;
    EmitVertex();
    mvPos = modelViewMatrix * vec4(gmvVertexPos[2], 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPos;
    mvVertexNormal=calculateTriangleNormal();
    mvVertexPos=mvPos.xyz;
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}

//fragment shader

in vec3 mvVertexNormal;
in vec3 mvVertexPos;

struct DirectionalLight {
    vec3 color;
    vec3 direction;
    float intensity;
};

const int MAX_DIRECTIONALLIGHT = 10;
uniform int USED_DIRECTIONALLIGHTS;
uniform DirectionalLight directionalLight[MAX_DIRECTIONALLIGHT];

vec4 calcDirectionalLight(DirectionalLight light, vec3 position, vec3 normal)
{
    return calcLightColor(light.color, light.intensity, position, normalize(light.direction), normal);
}

vec4 calcLightColor(vec3 light_color, float light_intensity, vec3 position, vec3 to_light_dir, vec3 normal)
{
    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    vec4 specColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Diffuse Light
    float diffuseFactor = max(dot(normal, to_light_dir), 0.0);
    diffuseColor = vec4(light_color, 1.0) * light_intensity * diffuseFactor;

    // Specular Light
    vec3 camera_direction = normalize(- position);
    vec3 from_light_dir = -to_light_dir;
    vec3 reflected_light = normalize(reflect(from_light_dir , normal));
    float specularFactor = max( dot(camera_direction, reflected_light), 0.0);
    specularFactor = pow(specularFactor, specularPower);
    specColor = light_intensity  * specularFactor * material.reflectance * vec4(light_color, 1.0);

    return (diffuseColor + specColor);
}

void main()
{


    vec4 totalLight = vec4(0);
    //directional Light
    for (int i=0; i<USED_DIRECTIONALLIGHTS; i++) {
        totalLight += calcDirectionalLight(directionalLight[i], mvVertexPos, mvVertexNormal);
    }
    //...

    fragColor = vec4(ambientLight, 1.0) + totalLight;
}
```

I am kinda new to shader so I dont know what to do anymore.
To specify the effect I get: the directional light that should only come from one direction (in worldSpace) comes from different directions based on the viewMatrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid now. I found the answer just after posting.

The geometry shader passes the vertexNormal directly instead of mutiplying it with the modelViewMatrix.

So the answer is this:

```
mvVertexNormal=normalize(modelViewMatrix * vec4(calculateTriangleNormal(), 0.0)).xyz;
```

instead of this:

```
mvVertexNormal=calculateTriangleNormal();
```