# Multiplication by a view matrix does not affect the resulting value in OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, shader, matrix-multiplication

To obtain constant directional light, I multiplied the view matrix by the light direction vector:

```
#version 300 es
uniform mat4 u_mvMatrix; // model-view matrix
uniform mat4 u_vMatrix; // view matrix
in vec4 a_position;
in vec3 a_normal;
const vec3 lightDirection = vec3(-1.9, 0.0, -5.0);
...
void main() {
    vec3 modelViewNormal = vec3(u_mvMatrix * vec4(a_normal, 0.0));
    vec3 lightVector = -(mat3(u_vMatrix) * lightDirection);
    float diffuseFactor = max(dot(modelViewNormal, lightVector), 0.0);
    ...
}
```

But the diffuseFactor value is the same as when use:

```
vec3 lightVector = -lightDirection;
```

In other words, it turns out the same worst picture.

**Question:** Can anyone please suggest why multiplication by a view matrix does not affect the resulting value diffuseFactor?

**Note:** The view matrix is created using:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, rmOffset:0, eyeX:0f, eyeY:0f, eyeZ:0f,
        centerX:0f, centerY:0f, centerZ:-4f, upX:0f, upY:1f, upZ:0f)
fun getVMatrixAsFloatBuffer(): FloatBuffer = Buffers.floatBuffer(viewMatrix)
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(vMatrixLink, 1, false, view.getVMatrixAsFloatBuffer());
```

I also checked the correctness of the view matrix using:

```
gl_Position = u_pMatrix * u_vMatrix * u_mMatrix * a_position;
```

This is working fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view matrix

> ```java
> Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 4f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
> ```

does not affect the viewing directing, because the upper left 3x3 of the view matrix is the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix).

Hence the operation

> ```c
> vec3 lightVector = -(mat3(u_vMatrix) * lightDirection);
> ```

multiplies the vector `lightDirection` by the identity matrix and doesn't change the vector at all.

Use different a point of view, to *see* the effect of the view matrix. For Instance:

```java
Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0f, 0f, 2.8f, 2.8f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
```